# java JAXB save subclass when saving

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm struggling saving all data from my class/subclass using JAXB.
I want to save all accounts from an observableList, but the problem is, the account class

```
public class Account{
     private ObjectProperty<HosterObject> host;
     ....
}
```

contains an HosterObject which has 2 attributes:
publicName and privateName also have getter and setter.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "hoster")
public class HosterObject {

private final StringProperty publicName;
private final StringProperty privateName;

public HosterObject(String publicName, String privateName){
    this.publicName = new SimpleStringProperty(publicName);
    this.privateName = new SimpleStringProperty(privateName);
}

@XmlElement(name = "publicName")
public StringProperty publicNameProperty(){
    return publicName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "privateName")
public StringProperty privateNameProperty(){
    return privateName;
}
```

How can I save the content from the Hosterobject as Element in the xml-file as well?
At the moment the xml file looks so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<accounts>
<account>
    <hoster/>
    <password>123</password>
    <status>unchecked</status>
    <username>test</username>
</account>
</accounts>
```

But i should look kinda like this

```
...
<account>
  <hoster>
    <publicName>Name</publicName>
    <privateName>private Name</privateName>
 </hoster>
 ....
 </account>
 ....
```

The code for saving:

```
public void saveAccountDataToFile(File file) {
try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AccountListWrapper.class);
    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    // Wrapping our person data.
    AccountListWrapper wrapper = new AccountListWrapper();
    wrapper.setAccounts(accountData);

    // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
    m.marshal(wrapper, file);
} catch (Exception e) { 
}
}
```

Wrapper:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "accounts")
public class AccountListWrapper {

private List<Account> accounts;

@XmlElement(name = "account")
public List<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to tag HosterObject  class? He must be taged if you want it in file, or you just dont show as whole code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I tried generating an own wrapper for the object and pass it here JAXBContext.newInstance(AccountListWrapper.class, HosterObjectWrapper.class);
But, i think, that isn't what you mean, or?

Comment: You must tag HosterObject by @XmlRootElement(name = "hoster") and tag @XmlElement method set for HosterObject in Account.

Comment: In HosterObject.java adding @XmlRootElement(name = "hoster")  and @XmlElement(name = "publicName") to public StringProperty publicNameProperty() and the same for privateName?

Comment: Yes :) You must tag class and set methods for fields.

Comment: I tried, but now the Exception is thrown
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
org.program.model.HosterObject does not have a no-arg default constructor.

Comment: Add constructor: public HosterObject (){} and public Account(){}, JAXB need this always.

Comment: It has. I updated the code to show you

Comment: I updated HosterObject code. Account is working with the wrapper and also has an public constructor

Comment: So its working or no ?

Comment: I don't know what exactly I changed but now its working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

tag HosterObject by

`@XmlRootElement(name = "hoster")`
`@XmlElement`

for class and set method for HosterObject in Account.

```
public HosterObject (){} 
public Account(){}
```

JAXB need default empty constructor.
If you want to add class to xml you must tag it and create always default public constructor. Remember to tag only class which are non abstract.